# Bat file that executes command with input from a txt file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to execute a batch file.

I want to open a URL using that batch file, but it needs to insert whatever what is inside a txt(or any file that supports easy editable text) before opening the URL.

For example:

bat file (which i will convert into an exe for easy usage)

```
@echo off
start http://website.com/WHATEVERISINTHEFILEBEHINDHERE
echo Opening website.
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 2000 >NUL. 2000
echo closing tool
```

The file which the bat needs to read from

```
steamid:123456789
```

Thank you.

Comment: Note: the text in the txt file(or config file in this case) will be edited.

Comment: only one line in your textfile?

Comment: Command __FOR__ is what you need to read in 1 or more lines from a text file into a variable. Open a command prompt window, execute `for /?` or `help for` and read the output help (several display pages). There can be found tons of __FOR__ examples on Stack Overflow. By the way: `steamid:123456789` can't be a valid name for a text file.

Comment: There is only a single line. oh and and i noticed a little mistake. The text file is named putsteamidhere.txt

Comment: The only content of that text file is "steamid:123456789"

Comment: Please provide all the extra information in your post by editing the question...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `for /f` to get every line of a file, but when it's sure, there is just one line (or you need just the first line of the file), there is an easier way:

```
@echo off
<putsteamidhere.txt set /p steamid=
start http://website.com/%steamid%
echo Opening website.
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 2000 >NUL
echo closing tool
```